# Listing post with Docpad and Jade

Tags: pug, docpad

I try to list my blog post content from another directory inside blog directory, it only output the jade content of the .jade file instead of rendered HTML content.

blog dir -> travel.html.jade, travel dir -> fristtrip.html.jade.

Here is my collection from *docpad.coffee*

```
blog: (database) ->
      database.findAllLive({pageOrder: $exists: true}, [pageOrder:1,title:1])
travel: (travel) ->
      travel.findAllLive({relativeOutDirPath:'blog/travel'},[date:-1])
```

the *travel.html.jade* file inside the blog directory

```
---
title: all of my trips
layout: page
tags: ['intro','page']
pageOrder: 1
dynamic: true
---

h2 All of my trips

nav.linklist
  each doc in getCollection('travel').toJSON()
    li
      h3 
        a(href=doc.url)= doc.title
      // =doc.contentRenderedWithouthLayout
      !=doc.content     //problem come here
      span= doc.date.toDateString()
```

Out put HTML blog page

```
All of my trips

My first trip 
p | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  
p | Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
p | Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum....
```

**please notice the p tag in my firsttrip.html.jade instead of rendered HTML content**

I try to solve with this link https://github.com/bevry/docpad/issues/167. I used *!{doc.contentRendered}* and *!{doc.contentRenderedWithoutLayout}* but it out put nothing

By the way I have another 2 question?

How can I limit the out put content, ex: 250 character each post?

How to paginate the travel page because I have so many post?

Comment: Tried with latest version of docpad and contentRenderedWithouthLayout works. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me:

```
text(render="jade")
  != doc.content
```